# Google Chrome downloading .zip file into .tgz

Tags: google-chrome

I am using amazon s3 to upload the files. it is working great but later on I found that a file which is uploaded and tried to download on windows chrome the file extension which is downloaded comes out to be example_file.tgz but on the S3 bucket the file is uploaded as example_file.zip . when i tried to download in mozilla firefox both in windows and linux, the file is downloaded in the correct extension
i just wanted to know the reason why only window's chrome is not downloading in the proper format ?

Comment: Go check the HTTP response headers in dev tools/network panel. See what value the `Content-Type` header has, and if additional headers suggesting a file name etc. are present.